# How to access a specific array element in java

Tags: java, arrays

I need to define specific numbers out of an array of 52 numbers so I can assign them an image (yes I am creating an applet). I don't think that code is necessary for any of you to answer this question. Any help would be fantastic.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Did you try searching for "array access Java"? Because the tutorial linked by @Boann is the first result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integer array access - Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060170/integer-array-access-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.  You can set an item in an array this way:

myArray[4] = 52;

That would set array index #4 (remember it's zero based so it's actually the 5th item) to the value of 52.  Is that what you're looking for?